# Serialization (using yasoo) of attr.ib which is is a list of attr.s fails

Tags: python, attr

```
from typing import List

import attr
from yasoo import serialize


@attr.s
class Bar:
    name = attr.ib()
    type = attr.ib()
    value = attr.ib()


@attr.s
class Foo:
    bars = attr.ib(type=List[Bar])


serialize(Foo([Bar('a', 'b', 'c'), Bar('a', 'b', 'c')]))
```

TypeError: Found object of type "Bar" which cannot be serialized

Is there a clean workaround for this limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is indeed a bug, but it is now fixed (fixed in version 0.2.1, see https://github.com/drorvinkler/yasoo/issues/1).

*I am the author of yasoo

Comment: Good as your answer can solve the question. If you can reference some article that shows this bug or the bug related your answer could be more helpful to others.

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes Thanks, I added a reference to the bug report.

Comment: @DrorVinkler, totally forgot to close this question out after you had closed the issue on GitHub. Thanks for the quick support!